# Medalha de Administrador duplicada?

Tags: bug, medalhas

Acabo de receber uma medalha de administrador, supostamente por ter completado 1000 análises na fila de edições sugeridas.

Duas coisas me pareceram estranhas:

- Faz tempo que não mexo nas filas, mas talvez algumas ações que faço como administrador contem como análises. Será?
- Percebi que eu já tinha essa medalha, ganha por atuação nessa mesma fila. Isso é mais estranho. Sei que posso ganhar várias medalhas de administrador em diferentes filas, mas duas na mesma fila me pareceu bug...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Também me aconteceu o mesmo e eu não mexo nas filas faz tempo.

Comment: Por um minuto cheguei a pensar que eu fosse uma pessoa especial. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[As regras foram alteradas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360198/401803), agora todos recebem uma medalha de Administrador para cada 1.000 análises feitas em uma fila. Veja [este comentário](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360194/steward-badges-being-re-awarded-suddenly#comment1201991_360194):

> *There's supposedly an announcement about review updates coming out today, if it hasn't been published somewhere yet. Seems the code is getting ahead of itself.*

Em tradução livre:

> Deveria ter sido feito um anúncio sobre esta mudança hoje, se já não foi publicado em algum lugar. Pelo visto o sistema foi atualizado antes.

---

Mas parece haver um [bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360194/steward-badges-being-re-awarded-suddenly#comment1202005_360194):

> This is my bug, caused by a temporary issue with and old batch job running after a migration took place. I have a fix I can roll out in a few.

Que aliás [já foi corrigido](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360214/401803).

Comment: Thanks. There still seems to be a bug, as I don't have 2k reviews yet. Not sure if that's what Brian Nickel was talking about, or if he was referring to the change being rolled-out network-wide before planned.